# Intento enviar un email por codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

Estoy intentado enviar un correo mediante el framework **codeigniter** pero recibo el siguiente error.

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message: fsockopen():
>   unable to connect to localhost:25 (Connection refused) Filename:
>   libraries/Email.php Line Number: 2061
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /var/www/html/test/application/controllers/Mantencion.php Line:
>   69 Function: send
>   File: /var/www/html/test/index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once

Aqui mi código.

```
$config = array();
            $config['useragent']           = "CodeIgniter";
            $config['mailpath']            = "/usr/sbin/sendmail"; // or "/usr/sbin/sendmail"
            $config['protocol']            = "smtp";
            $config['smtp_host']           = "localhost";
            $config['smtp_port']           = "25";
            $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
            $config['charset']  = 'utf-8';
            $config['newline']  = "\r\n";
            $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

            $this->load->library('email');

            $this->email->initialize($config);

            $this->email->from('mail@gmail.com', 'admin');
            $this->email->to('tome@gmail.cl');

            $this->email->subject('Тест Email');
            $this->email->message('ASDADS');
            // $this->email->message($this->load->view('email/'.$type.'-html', $data, TRUE));

            if ($this->email->send()) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', '  Correo enviado exitosamente');
            }
            show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
```

Estoy usando Linux Mint. Una consulta debo instalar un servicio para poder enviar un correo?

Answer (score 0):

Debes tener un servidor de correos instalado o usar alguno externo (mailgun por ejemplo). 
El mensaje te indica que no puede conectarse al SMTP por el puerto 25 (no está abierto).